# Retrofit 2 отправка изображения на сервер

Tags: android, retrofit2, gson

Пытаюсь отправить изображение на сервер в виде массива байт следующим образом

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(getPath(Uri.parse(photoPath))));

        byte[] buf;
        buf = new byte[in.available()];

        while (in.read(buf) != -1);

        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody
                .create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"), buf);

        uploadImage(token, "quest", id, requestBody)
            .subscribe(s -> {

            }, throwable -> {
                Log.d("tag", throwable.toString())
            });

private Single<String> uploadImage(String token, String model, int id, RequestBody bytes) {
    return putImage(token, model, id, bytes);
}

@PUT("image")
Single<String> putImage(
        @Header("Authorization") String token,
        @Query("model") String model,
        @Query("id") int id,
        @Body RequestBody bytes
);
```

но вываливается ошибка

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

как я понимаю, что это из-за gson но не понятно как исправить, может кто знает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в коде все правильно, ошибка здесь

```
Single<String> putImage
```

в ответе с сервера объект а не строка